# _view.findViewById(R.id.visualizer) returns null

Tags: java, android

I would like to use the method `setPlayer()` but I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> com.chibde.visualizer.LineBarVisualizer.setPlayer(int)' on a null
> object reference

```java
public class Scanner {
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    public View _view;
    private Context _context;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void toggle(View view, Context context) {
        this._view = view;
        this._context = context;

        // Activate the scanner
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            this.start();
        }
        // Deactivate the scanner
        else {
            this.stop();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForColorStateLists")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void start() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(_context, scanner);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            // Bar
            int audioSessionId = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
            if (audioSessionId != -1) {
                LineBarVisualizer lineBarVisualizer = _view.findViewById(R.id.visualizer);

                // Set you media player to the visualizer.
                lineBarVisualizer.setPlayer(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it seems like the value of `lineBarVisualizer` is *null*. This is how I pass the view from my MainActivity class to my Scanner class:

```java
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void requestAudioPermissions(View view) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //When permission is not granted by user, show them message why this permission is needed.
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant permissions to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
    }
    //If permission is granted, then go ahead recording audio
    else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Go ahead with recording audio now
        _scanner.toggle(view, MainActivity.this);
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
        }

        // Scanner
        scanner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForColorStateLists")
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                requestAudioPermissions(view);
            }
        });
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    <com.chibde.visualizer.LineBarVisualizer
        android:id="@+id/visualizer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Why is it *null*?

Comment: Please add the XML file of the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //The view received at onClick is the button's view.
            requestAudioPermissions(view);
        }
```

The `button` `view` doesn't contain `visualizer`

The solution is to change

`_view.findViewById(R.id.visualizer);`

to

`((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.visualizer);`

or

Move the functions toggle and start to the `Main Activity` where you will have native access to `findViewById(R.id.visualizer);`

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the first way. I have tried it with `LineBarVisualizer lineBarVisualizer = ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.visualizer);` but I get the error _Cannot resolve symbol 'context'_.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I have now replaced `context` with `_context` and it works fine. Thank you!